# protoc not finding things in proto_path

Tags: protocol-buffers, protoc

I'm finding that `protoc` doesn't seem to find things which are on the `proto_path` despite them being present:

```
$ protoc --proto_path=protobufs/protobufs \
    --go_out=plugins=grpc:/home/me/go/src somefolder/enums.proto
somefolder/enums.proto: No such file or directory
$ ls protobufs/protobufs/somefolder/enums.proto 
protobufs/protobufs/somefolder/enums.proto
```

Why might this happen? It doesn't seem to happen to others. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, and `protoc --version` says `libprotoc 3.0.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this command?

```
protoc --proto_path=protobufs/protobufs \
    --go_out=plugins=grpc:/home/me/go/src \
    protobufs/protobufs/somefolder/enums.proto
```

The `proto_path` argument is used to tell `protoc` where should it look for import proto files.

Comment: Ah. That works. So it seems like my command above doesn't work and never should have done, so I need to find out why it works for everyone else! Thank you!